# ZF2, get module name in view, how?

Tags: zend-framework2

Have just finished tutorial by Rob Allen:
http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework-2.pdf

then i decided to get module name in view, to make menu between application module & albums module, as i see could implement this, i was able to get module name.

How can i get in layout when any module is requested? (this menu is global).

I am very new to the ZF2, and i understand that i misunderstanding the concept, but can't understand where :)

Any help will be useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module names are tricky as there isn't actually the concept of a module in the dispatcher.

You would have to put it into the layout yourself. The easiest way to do this is from the controller:

```
function indexAction()
{
    $this->layout()->module = __NAMESPACE__;

    // do stuff and return a view model
}
```

Ideally, you should not need to know this information and work entirely with route names.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try investigate how i can implement this using route names :)

Answer (score 0):

For menus/navigation, I suggest to use Zend Navigation.